# Why are there different Ethernet PHY magnetic configurations?

Tags: ethernet, magnetics, phy

I'm looking at pcb-mount Ethernet ports like these:

[image]

I'm seeing a few different configurations of the magnetics within the ports. On a single Wurth data sheet, there are 4:
[image]

Schematic 2 is the part we currently use, but is going obsolete. I found potential replacements which look more like Schematic 1.

What is the difference? Are there benefits to the different designs?

Comment: Schematic 4 is gigabit magjack. Others are for fast ethernet (100mbps), with different LPF design...(and performance I suppose).

Comment: I would like to know it, too.

Comment: Schematic 2 is non-symmetric, thus can not be used for MDI/MDIX implementations. When I was developing network card, there was recommended part to use, but I selected another similar part (from WE by the way) with the same internal circuit, got it approved by chip manufacturer and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Schematic 1 offers direct connection to the center tap of the exterior
port windings, and is suitable for PoE connection (which may either
draw power, or supply power, over twisted pair).   Schematics 2 and 4
do not have low-resistance connection suitable for PoE.   Schematic #3
does technically have the ability to connect to PoE, but only
through an inductor (which may saturate).

Modern designs would usually allow bidirectional use of
the four lanes, and #2 does not.   It is not surprising that it may
become obsolete, in favor of #4.